# Error in table and cannot xtfrm data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, datatable, arguments

I have a problem trying to run this in R:

```
families=with(sv.data, table(Family, Altitude))
```

but I got this:

```
Error in table(Family, Altitude) : 
  all arguments must have the same length
In addition: Warning message:
In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
```

I do not know what it means. The table does not have any mistakes.

Can someone help me?

I am attaching an example of my table

[image]

Comment: Please show the `str(sv.data)`.  In the attached image, it didn't show the column names Family or Altitude

Comment: print = str (sv.data)
'data.frame': 595 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ ï..Family       : chr  "Adoxaceae" "Adoxaceae" "Adoxaceae" "Adoxaceae" ...
 $ Genus           : chr  "Viburnum" "Viburnum" "Viburnum" "Viburnum" ...
 $ Specific.Epithet: chr  "urbanii" "urbanii" "urbanii" "urbanii" ...
 $ Species         : chr  "Viburnum_urbanii" "Viburnum_urbanii" "Viburnum_urbanii" "Viburnum_urbanii" ...
 $ Altitude        : int  3250 3160 3160 2820 3320 3320 3320 3320 3320 3320 ...
 $ Plant.Number    : int  375 357 361 226 499 534 553 567 585 588 ...

Comment: seems like the Family show some extra prefix `ï..Family`

Comment: Can you try `with(sv.data, table(ï..Family, Altitude))`